# echo global variable in html source

Tags: php, html

I have two global variables declared in my config.php file, I would like to call one of these depending on results from another page however I need some help with my syntax.

It simply add a class to the button (`btn-success` or `btn-default`)

**config.php**

```
define("BTN_SUCCESS", "btn-success");
define("BTN_DEFAULT", "btn-default");
```

I want to do something like the following but it doesn't work it simply prints out the names in my html source;

```
echo '<td>
<button id="fav" type="button" class="btn '.BTN_SUCCESS. || 'BTN_DEFAULT''"></button>
</td>';
```

If I insert either of them individually they work but it's not what I want, for example;

```
echo '<td>
<button id="fav" type="button" class="btn '.BTN_SUCCESS.'"></button>
</td>';
```

I want an or operator in there - is this possible? It's probably something simple. Quite new to php so any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Rizier123 I guess he tries to do what corresponds to || in JS. So he wants to use `BTN_SUCCESS` if it's defined, else he wants to use `BTN_DEFAULT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
echo '<td>
<button id="fav" type="button" class="btn '.(BTN_SUCCESS?:BTN_DEFAULT).'"></button>
</td>';
```

The parenthesis is shorthand for

```
if(BTN_SUCCESS) 
    echo BTN_SUCCESS;
 else
    echo BTN_DEFAULT;
```

The if-condition above can be shortened using [ternary operators](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-ternary-operator/):

```
echo BTN_SUCCESS ? BTN_SUCCESS : BTN_DEFAULT;
```

And if you want to echo the value of the condition (in this case `BTN_SUCCESS`) if it's truthful you can shorten it even more by removing the middle part (as of PHP 5.3):

```
echo BTN_SUCCESS ?: BTN_DEFAULT;
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP (and future visitors to SO) why you did what you did. "Try this" doesn't make this a good answer.

Comment: He has both constants defined so this doesn't makes sense

Answer (score 5):

You need to first set the class depending on the value, then echo the class.

```
<?php
    $class = $somethingIsTrue ? BTN_SUCCESS : BTN_DEFAULT;

?>

echo '<td>
<button id="fav" type="button" class="btn '.$class.'"></button>
</td>';
```

Comment: This is not answering the question!, it's just guessing what OP means and that should be done with comments